# How to find a dynamic node class by pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this WP plugin and I've been trying to get the ID of a custom post kinda thing that is declared in the body class on each page. So it goes like this;

```
<body class="(Bunch of other classes) ld-courses-1731-parent">
```

I'm trying to get the number 1731 in my JS function but the number is dynamic so I need to some regex matching with the string pattern.

Pattern: `ld-courses-*INT VALUE*-parent`

how can I do this with JS? Any help is much appreciated thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match if thats the only class in your body:

```js
var classList = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList;
[...classList].forEach(function(thisClass) {
  if (/ld-courses-\b/.test(thisClass)) {
    var id = thisClass.match(/\d/g);
    console.log(id.join(""));
  }
});
```

```html
<body class="another-class-before another-class-12-hasnum ld-courses-1731-parent another-class-12-hasnumaswell another-class-after">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no unfortunately, a typical Wordpress site has like 20-30 body classes

Comment: I updated the code. But I have very little knowledge of regex. It would currently check for the first linse if it matches ld-courses- then return the digits inside. It won't match whats next of the digits tho, and I feel you need that as well

Comment: Oh man, you rock! I'm sure this would do the job but I'll just research it a bit more to find out if I can match what's after the digits as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi Laclogan in regards to your question yes it's possible for sure.

Correct me if i'm wrong but the number comes probably if it's changing for each post directly from the url.

The following site explains if this is the case how to get that number from the url.
https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

In addition you can use the function concat to combine the strings see this site for an example hope it helps.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Could you confirm for me that the number is always present in the url or if this is not the case?

Comment: Also could you provide us a example page url so that we can take a look at what kind parametername is being used.

Comment: Oh no man, URL has nothing to do with the body class, current URL format is set to pretty permalinks format and it doesn't contain any info about the number I'm dealing with. I think the regex solution above will do the job tho, thank you

Comment: Maybe then take a look at this website https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/26 sorry don't have enough reputation to comment under prosy his answer. https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure to check them out.